# <a href="file.pdf"> is not working. It's inside another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="content" class="gallery-images-container">
   <div class="box-gutter"></div>
   <div class="box-sizer"></div>

   <div class="box hvr-grow">
     <a href="images/machine/triax.png"><img alt="Agra picture" src="images/machine/triax.png"></a>
     <div class="center">
        <h4>Triax Super 120 Cutter</h4>
        <a href="assets/Super masonry-bridge-saw.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box hvr-grow">
       <a href="images/machine/triax1.png"><img alt="Agra picture" src="images/machine/triax1.png"></a>
       <div class="center">
         <h4>Triax Block Cutter</h4>
         <a href="assets/5-600 block cutter masonry-block-saw.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a> 

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: image 1]

[![image 2][2]][2]

So i am using a div tag that has download pdf option inside another div which pops up the image. So when I click on download PDF, its opening the pop up window and it says Image could not be loaded. I am not so good in javascript so I don't know how to fix it ..Please help me.

EDIT:  The link works when I click on open in new tab, But does not when I click on it directily.

Here's the link for the live preview of template: http://www.templatemo.com/live/templatemo_478_accord ..Please see the gallery section.

Comment: please add a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: I'm new here...plz tell me how do I do that

Comment: can you share entire code?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Right. First priority to Snippet !

Answer (score 2):

Use `download` attribute in `a` tag to enable download option

```
<a href="assets/5-600 block cutter masonry-block-saw.pdf" download>Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: I just checked, the link works when I click open in new tab, It won't work when I click on it directily. .. I have provided the live preview of the template i am editing in the question.. Please see the gallery section and suggest me something.

Comment: Where is PDF in [this link](http://www.templatemo.com/live/templatemo_478_accord)?

Comment: I have created another div tag and I put the PDF file in there..Now I think the external div tag is preventing the pdf file from opening... I have created another div because I have to write the product name and that border..Please see the image.

Comment: I can't see PDF or Download PDF link anywhere on the page that you have provided in question.

Comment: <a href="assets/Super masonry-bridge-saw.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>  I had to remove an image to post the link for template because I cannot post more than two links ..On the image above if you look behind,  you will see download PDF below the machine name.

Answer (score 0):

Under some conditions, embedded spaces must be encoded as %20 
href="assets/Super masonry-bridge-saw.pdf"

Comment: Entire code of what? CSS or Javascript or HTML ? I think its Javascript , Instead of opening the pdf link, It's opening that pop up thing. The problem is I don't know Javascript.

Comment: if adding download tag won't work try to remove your javascript then test it

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="assets/5-600 block cutter masonry-block-saw.pdf" download="fileName.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

You have to make it accessible to download with the download tag. The download tag also controls what name the user will download the pdf as.

Comment: I just checked, the link works when I click open in new tab, It won't work when I click on it directily.

Comment: @AnuragNandi as many people have suggested, with these changes. Also replace the pdf name to something simple maybe just blockcutter.pdf since that name is internal anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the HREF for PDF "/5-600 block cutter masonry-block-saw.pdf". The space in the URL should be replaced. I recommend naming all the PDF files without space.

## Updated

Apologies for this I checked, spaces is not causing issue

However, when I see your code,

```
    function init_masonry(){
      var $container = $('#content');

      $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.box',
            isAnimated: true
        });
      });
    }
```

All the media in the box is being animated with javascript.If you move the PDF file outside this *div* it should work. Try to assign another selector to the PDF image.

Comment: I don't think spaces usually cause a problem. The browser will translate it to `%20` when sending the request to the server.

Comment: I have changed the PDF file names..  But the problem is not the file name, It's Javascript, Its opening the pop up window instead of pdf file

Comment: @AnuragNandi For me the code is working fine. Can you please add JS

Comment: I just checked, the link works when I click open in new tab, It won't work when I click on it directily. .. I have provided the live preview of the template i am editing in the question.. Please see the gallery section and suggest me something.

Comment: Hi Mohit ..Thanks a lot ..that's exactly the problem that's causing the issue, But i I place this links outside the div, It wont show the output.. maybe the javascript is configured that way. It wont display the text that is outside the div and Even If i add text, it is misaligning with other images. Can you please help me with that?